# Python compare matching keys and print values, keys

Tags: python

I know there are somewhat similar questions to this, but none have answered specifically what I'm trying to do and I haven't had any luck with it. I have two dictionaries and I want to print out the key and values if the values of it are larger than the or not in dictionary two.

So for instance:

```
dict1 = {'T': 5, 'X': 10, 'Y': 15, 'Z': 25}
dict2 = {'U': 10, 'X': 11, 'Y': 15, 'Z': 15}
```

How do I get it to only print 'T': 5, 'Z': 25?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for key in dict1:
    if key not in dict2 or dict1[key] > dict2[key]:
        print("'%s': %d" % (key, dict1[key]))
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your help.